# Uninitialized string offset in php

Tags: php, arrays, string

I looked to other questions that looked like mine,but couldn't find a good answer. So

```
$machines = get_machine($platform);
$options = array() ;
$options[0] = "please select";
foreach( (array)$machines as $machine_){
    $options[$machine_[0]] = $machine_[1] ;
    array_push($temp,$machine_[0]); 
}

//print_r($options);

$form->addElement(new Element\Select("Existing machines :", "machine", array("onchange" => "this.form.submit()", "value" => $machine)));
if ( !in_array( $machine, $temp ) )
    $machine = 0;

$form->addElement(new Element\Textbox("Add new/Edit machine:", "new_machine", array("placeholder" => "new machine", "shortDesc" => "Add new machine or edit the existing one", "value" => get_machine( $machine ))));
```

It says that the "machine" is not defined and unitialized offset .
Here is defined :

```
if ( isset($_POST['machine']) ) $mask = $_POST['machine']; else $machine = 0;
```

I had the exact same code with other variables and it didn't gave me an error of such nature. I am sure,that there are no typos.

Comment: You can add this above your if condition `$mask =  $machine = "";`

Comment: Thanks,that helped with the undifined part.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure this will get me another barrage of downvotes but one method that helped me keeping my statements short and readable (without doing `isset($_POST['...'])` all the time and everywhere) is placing an initialisation of the expected values at the top of my page and **directly underneath it** an `extract($_POST)` command like:

```
$amount=$mask=$machine=0; $flag1=$flag2=$flag2=false;
extract($_POST);
```

Yes, this *will* turn *everything* that has been posted into a php variable on my page, but ...

1. it needs to have been `posted` there in the first place (so that reduces the scope)
2. it will either be ignored (if it was an unasked variable) or reset later to its proper value in my own code.

The benefit is that after this initialisation I don't need to bother with any `isset()`s any more. I just use the intended variable directly. It will be there, either in its initialised form (with a value of 0 or `false`) or as a consequence of the `extract()` statement.